# TestNG.xml > only Executing First TestNG Test

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

TestNG.xml > only Executing First TestNG Test

1. I have copied the exact same working project, setup etc on a new device(PC) but when executing the same testng.xml it seems to execute only the first @Test across all test cases.
2. Running the test on my existing system works correctly.
3. For example **@Test(priority = 1)** only seems to be executing across all my 100+ TestNG Test classes.

**Example Test File:**

```
    @Test(priority = 1)
public void LoadPage() throws Exception {
    basePage.loadPage();

    //Logs whether the Url and page Title is correct
    DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
    Log.info("@PASS ---> Expected Site URL: " +  basePage.page_url + "  |  Found the following Site URL: " +  basePage.getPageUrl());
    Log.info("@PASS ---> Expected Page Title: " +  basePage.page_title + "  |  Found the following title: " +  basePage.getPageTitle());
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void hutLocaliseAndSelectOrderType() throws Exception {
    phHomepage.enterHutPostcode();
    hutLocalisePage.selectOrderType();
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void SignIntoAccount() throws Exception {
    basePage.pageJSLoadAndClick(pageHeader.button_SignIn);

    //Sign into Account
    signInPage.signIntoAccount();

    //Validate whether Sign Out button is visible, once successfully signed into account
    pageHeader.signOutButtonIsDisplayed();
}


**Listed in BasePage.java class**
public void loadPage() throws Exception{
    driver.get(page_url);
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), getPageUrl());
    Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), getPageTitle());
}

<suite name="PH_Automation_Scripts_by_GBruno" verbose="2">
<test name="PH Automation Tests: Pizza Combinations" parallel="false">
     <packages>
        <package name="PhFramework.pizzas.*" /> 
    </packages> 
</test>
```

If i alter the above testng.xml to execute one test at a time the test executes fine.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Check your run / debug configurations on your new machine.

Comment: Hi @Moshisho im currently using Eclipse IDE, is there a specific way to check the debug config in Eclipse?

Comment: I'm more familiar with IntelliJ, but you can search for it. How are you running the tests, right click on a test, command line, etc..?

Comment: ok @Moshisho currently im running the tests using a TestNg.xml, please refer to the following link:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592208/testng-xml-not-executing-classes-one-by-one

Comment: @Phil_P85 - Which post would you like to pursue to get answers ? I have updated the other post with some questions. So maybe you can have this closed off ?

Answer (score 0):

@Phil_P85 - This is your testng xml file.

```
<suite name="PH_Automation_Scripts_by_GBruno" verbose="2">
<test name="PH Automation Tests: Pizza Combinations" parallel="false">
     <packages>
        <package name="PhFramework.pizzas.*" /> 
    </packages> 
</test>
```

Can you describe 'PhFramework.pizzas.*' ? If 'pizzas' is your package, can you try doing just '' see if it works.