# testng.xml not executing classes one by one

Tags: testng, testng-eclipse

**PhFramework.pizzas.bbqMeatFeast.cheesyBites.LargeTest** should execute all tests before proceeding to **PhFramework.pizzas.bbqMeatFeast.classicCrust.LargeTest**

TestNG seems to be executing the first @Test within all the classes, if i execute only one Test Class at a time it works fine.

[image]

**testng.xml code:** the following will fail, but if i remove one of the classes it works. 
[image]

Please can somebody advice what could cause this issue?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line no 4 of your testng.xml, it should be:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" preserve-order="true">
```

Comment: still the same issue persists, even when adding a thread count of 1 both tests are getting executed at the same time.

Comment: For example: class1 should execute then class2, 
Instead class1 and class2 are executing in parallel, the testng.xml file that i have setup works on my other machine; maybe something external could be triggering the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`preserver-order="true"` should be in the `<test>` tag, not the `<suite>` tag

Comment: thanks @nofacade but even applying the above code still fails, it seems to execute both of the test classes at the same time? but parallel="false" and even when i add a thread count of 1

Comment: hmm, are you sure you're running the correct testng.xml file? By default testng executes tests in order in the xml file.

Comment: Yes @nofacade, its strange, the testng.xml works on my other machine which has the exact same setup,its as it fails to execute the test cases correctly when one+ test classes are executed

Answer (score 0):

Notice your packages' names, you have different packages, maybe you have same classes names on two packages?

Comment: the class names are different one is 'Medium' and the other one is 'Large' so its pointing to the correct classes, i just cant seem to stop them from executing in order and not at the same time :/

Comment: The class names are different but notice 'PhFramework.pizzas.bbqMeatFeast.classicCrust' and 'PhFramework.Margarita.pam'

Comment: yes @Moshisho that is correct, both are stored within different packages but this shouldnt impact the execution phase, even using a wildcard which will execute all classes and packages still fails and this also works on my other system which is using the exact same project

Comment: If you try putting in the xml the package name that worked e.g. bbq... It still fails the same?

Comment: yes it still does the same thing either execute both classes at the same time or execute only the first @Test of each class

Comment: @Phil_P85 - We would need a bit of a debug data to figure out more. So can you please add verbose="5" to your suite xml file and then run it once again and share the debug logs here ? [ Maybe you can just update your question itself with the link to the debug logs ] You can perhaps post the debug logs on gist.github.com and share a link in your question.